# oracle count null per columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Pandas is offering

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

to count the NAN values per each column. Is there something similar in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

No idea what Pandas is but good old `CASE` should do (and it works in all major database engines):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN column_name IS NULL THEN 1 END) ...
```

Comment: and ... continues with like `from table_name` basically

Comment: Sure. But you manually need to specify all columns? Is there a solution where this is performed automatically?

Comment: That's another question. You need to look into dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(column_name)
FROM   table_name
```

`COUNT(*)` (or, equivalently, `COUNT(1)`) will count rows regardless of whether any columns have `NULL` values and `COUNT(column_name)` will count the non-`NULL` values (and, if it exists, can use an index on that column).

Comment: Sure. But you manually need to specify all columns? Is there a solution where this is performed automatically?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler How would the database know which columns you want to calculate the number of `NULL`s for if you did not specify the columns? There are no ways in SQL of repeating the same thing for all columns (unless you are going to use dynamic SQL and queries on the data dictionary but that is going to be less efficient).

Comment: Is there no way to simply use ALL columns in a table? Maybe via PLSQL?

Comment: I will need to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528682/count-null-values-from-multiple-columns-with-sql and https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benjamin/2013/12/27/sql-tip-counting-null-values/