# How to find the total number of orphan records in a schema in oracle. Result should be displayed as Child_table,Parent_table, No. of orphan records

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find the total number of orphan records in a schema in oracle. Result should be displayed as Child_table,Parent_table, No. of orphan records

Comment: use Not Exists while joining both parent and child table

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

How do would the database know there is an orphan record?

If you have foreign key constraints set up on the tables then you should not have any orphan records unless you are allowing `NULL` values in the foreign key or using `ON DELETE SET NULL` - in which case you just need to go through every [foreign key in the data dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730054/1509264) and [count the `NULL` values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45460487/1509264) in the foreign key columns of those tables.