# How can I count all NULL values, without column names, using SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm reading and executing sql queries from file and I need to inspect the result sets to count all the null values across all columns. Because the SQL is read from file, I don't know the column names and thus can't call the columns by name when trying to find the null values.

I think using CTE is the best way to do this, but how can I call the columns when I don't know what the column names are?

```
WITH query_results AS
(
<sql_read_from_file_here>
)
select count_if(<column_name> is not null) FROM query_results
```

Comment: [It may be used as inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932559/5070879)

Comment: Do you know the number of columns? Can you show us how you are loading the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python to read the file of SQL statements, you can do something like this which uses `pglast` to parse the SQL query to get the columns for you:

```
import pglast
sql_read_from_file_here = "SELECT 1 foo, 1 bar"
ast = pglast.parse_sql(sql_read_from_file_here)
cols = ast[0]['RawStmt']['stmt']['SelectStmt']['targetList']
sum_stmt = "sum(iff({col} is null,1,0))"
sums = [sum_sql.format(col = col['ResTarget']['name']) for col in cols]
print(f"select {' + '.join(sums)} total_null_count from query_results")


# outputs: select sum(iff(foo is null,1,0)) + sum(iff(bar is null,1,0)) total_null_count from query_results
```