# dbt macro using Jinja in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, macros, jinja2, dbt

I am trying to compare some columns in an automated way, the column types that i am comparing can be: float, integer, string or date / timestamps but I am having issues with the syntax and how to best cover the last condition i.e when I have dates/timestamps

This is what I have so far but somehow i am getting type errors. Plus I am not sure if what i have done would work or not since i am stuck at the very initial stage.

```
{% macro find_mismatch_s1_s2_(s1_col, s2_col,field) -%}
{%if type(s1_col) is string %}
  if(coalesce({{s1_col}},"") != coalesce({{s2_col}},""),true,false ) as is_{{field}}_mismatch
{%- elif type(s1_col) is float or type(s1_col) is integer -%}
  if(coalesce({{s1_col}},0) != coalesce({{s2_col}},0),true,false) as is_{{field}}_mismatch
{% else %}
  if(coalesce({{s1_col}},{{another_macro_that_gets_a_date}}) != coalesce({{s2_col}},{{another_macro_that_gets_a_date}}),true,false) as is_{{field}}_mismatch
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

- First I am checking if the column type is string if yes, then compare the values of two columns, if values are null then use blank to compare
- Second I am checking if the column types are float or integer, if yes compare two columns and if there is null then compare with 0
- lastly, I am covering the case of dates/timestamps, I couldn't find the type() for the date / timestamp so I added it to the else statement, which might not be the best thing,  would be great if someone can also recommend how to best cover these cases.
- The reason I am adding the `coalesce` statements is because if any of the value in one of the columns is null, the `is_{{field}}_mismatch` would return false, even though it should be true
- if I enter empty strings as a part of the `coalesce` for the second and third cases, it will run into error due to column type, hence I have to add these in seperate if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in your database does not flow through the code you write in Jinja -- jinja templates a sql query before that query is executed.

When you write `type(s1_col)`, you might expect to get the data type of the data in the database column named `s1_col`, but actually you will always get a `string` type, since the variable `s1_col` is a string that holds the name of a database column.

You can write this logic in a type-agnostic way by returning true if either column is null (in sql, not jinja):

```sql
{% macro find_mismatch_s1_s2_(s1_col, s2_col,field) -%}
case
    when {{ s1_col }} is null and {{ s2_col }} is not null
    then true
    when {{ s2_col }} is null and {{ s1_col }} is not null
    then true
    when {{ s1_col }} is null and {{ s2_col }} is null
    then false
    else {{ s1_col }} != {{ s2_col }}
end as is_{{field}}_mismatch
{% endmacro %}
```

Another option, if you really need the data type, is to use dbt's `adapter` class, specifically the [`get_columns_in_relation`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/adapter#get_columns_in_relation) method. The returned List of Columns have a `data_type` property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730868/get-column-names-and-types-using-star-macro-in-dbt/72736650#72736650) for more info.

Comment: so we can't use these functions: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#builtin-tests

Comment: you can use those functions; the problem is getting the variables (in the jinja context) to contain the values that you want to test

Comment: hey do you think you can help me with this logic as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404333/looping-through-columns-passed-to-an-existing-macro-in-dbt