# looping through columns passed to an existing macro in DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, macros, jinja2, dbt

I have a macro that creates a boolean field with the values 0 and 1. The 0 and 1 are generated due to the fact that I am comparing values from two columns i.e s1, s2

- s1 - represents a column name that needs to be compared of a given column passed as parameter 1 column
- s2 - represents the second column that needs to be compared

s1 columns: x, y ,z
s2 columns: x2, y2, z2

x column is compared with x2 column, similarly y column with y2 column and z with z2 column.

column

- 8 values are passed to both s1 and s2 to make the comparison hence, the below macro is being called 8 times:

***macro:***

```
{% macro create_value(s1, s2) -%}
if(ifnull({{s1}} != {{s2}},true) is true,1,0) as {{ s1 | replace('xx','new') }}
{% endmacro %}
```

***Calling the macro:***

```
compute_value as (
select *,
    {{ create_value('xx_col1','xx_col2') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col3','xx_col4') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col5','xx_col6') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col7','xx_col8') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col9','xx_col10') }},
    ...
    {{ create_value('xx_col15','xxcol_16') }},
from
table
)
```

running the above macro will create the 8 new columns that are:

- new_col1
- new_col3
- new_col5
- new_col7
- new_col9
- new_col11
- new_col13
- new_col15

Once I have these 8 columns, I have to calculate the sum of the values
Till this point I have everything. Currently, I am doing it manually by writing all the column names generated from the first macro and summing them up (see below):

```
select
*,
    new_col1 + new_col3 + new_col5 + new_col7 ....... + new_col15 AS new_value

from compute_value
```

Technically, I am getting my answers right, what I would like to automate is the calculation of the column `new_value`.

My first macro creates 8 columns and then I have to manually write the names of all 8 columns and sum them up. Is there a way that the sum of these columns can be automated as well i.e removing this part:

```
    new_col1 + new_col3 + new_col5 + new_col7 ....... + new_col5 AS new_value
```

currently, the complete code looks like this:

```
compute_value as (
select *,
    {{ create_value('xx_col1','xx_col2') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col3','xx_col4') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col5','xx_col6') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col7','xx_col8') }},
    {{ create_value('xx_col9','xx_col10') }},
    ...
    {{ create_value('xx_col15','xxcol_16') }},
from
table
),

select 
*,
    new_col1 + new_col2 + new_col3 + new_col4 + new_col5 + new_col6 + new_col7 + new_col8 AS new_value

from compute_value
```

***I need the 8 boolean values as well as the total sum of those values as the output***

Answer (score 1):

You could DRY this up a little by creating a jinja list, storing the names of the columns in that list, and looping over it twice. With only 8 columns, this might not save you much typing, and would arguably be harder to read, but it would look like this:

```sql
{% set cols = [("xxcol1", "col2"), ("xxcol3", "col4"), ("xxcol5", "col6"), ("xxcol7", "col8"), ...] %}
select
    {% for col1, col2 in cols %}
    {{ create_value(col1, col2) }},
    {% endfor %}
    {% for col1, _ in cols -%}
    {{ col1 | replace('xx','new_') }}{% if not loop.last %} +{% endif %}
    {%- endfor %} as new_value,
...
```

Compiles to:

```sql
select
    {{ create_value(xxcol1, col2) }},
    {{ create_value(xxcol3, col4) }},
    {{ create_value(xxcol5, col6) }},
    {{ create_value(xxcol7, col8) }},
    new_col1 + new_col3 + new_col5 + new_col7 as new_value,
...
```

If you RDBMS does not support lateral column aliases, you have to rework your macro to pull out the aliasing:

```sql
{% macro create_value(s1, s2) -%}
if(ifnull({{s1}} != {{s2}},true) is true,1,0)
{% endmacro %}
```

and then just call the macro in each loop:

```sql
{% set cols = [("xxcol1", "col2"), ("xxcol3", "col4"), ("xxcol5", "col6"), ("xxcol7", "col8"), ...] %}
select
    {% for col1, col2 in cols %}
    {{ create_value(col1, col2) }} as {{ col1 | replace('xx','new_') }},
    {% endfor %}
    {% for col1, col2 in cols -%}
    {{ create_value(col1, col2) }}{% if not loop.last %} +{% endif %}
    {%- endfor %} as new_value,
...
```

Comment: the issues here is that the col1,col2,....col8 are actually being created by the macro that i added above, this produces 1 or 0 that i need to sum up later, so not sure how will the list help me, plus {{ create_value(col,'col_2') }} this will probably not work, since col_1 and col_2 are changing everytime in my macro (the bolean comparision is between different columns)

Comment: This produces something very similar to the example you shared in your question. Please update your question with a better example so we can help you.

Comment: hey, thanks for getting back to me. I have actually added more descriptions. I need both values from boolean as well as the total sum. The macro `create_value` takes 8 columns which are changing each time, for example, comparing x with x1 and y with y2 , z with z2 etc where x,yz are `s1` and x2,y2,z2 are `s2`. In your code, I am not sure what I need to add to the list that you have created  i.e `cols`, and what I need to pass to the parameter `col_2` since it will have to change 8 times.

Comment: In your example (still), you're using `col_1` and `col_2` repeatedly when calling your macro. What does this actually look like? Is there a pattern in the names of these columns? Are the `col_1` and `col_2` columns drawn from the same list? There are lots of options for how to iterate through these programmatically, but I need more info on what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry i fixed it the col_1 and col_2 are always different columns. you can think of it for example countr_1 compared to company_2, if they match my macro returns 0 if they don't it returns 1. Similarly, in the next call of macro the columns could be state1 vs state 2. Then based on the 0 and 1 I am creating a score

Comment: the pattern would be tha after xxx_ the names are similar for example col_1 and col_2 would be: s1_country , and s2_country. s1_state vs s2_state. I have a table that contains all these columns: country_1, country_2, state_1, state_2. Macro compares these columns and in the end score is calculated based on boolean values 0 and 1 from the macro

Comment: before you left your last comment, I updated my answer by using a list of tuples, where each tuple gets unpacked into the call to the macro. But if there is another way to build the list of column names, do that. See `dbt_utils.get_filtered_columns_in_relation`: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_filtered_columns_in_relation-source

Comment: i will test your code and will let you know under the comments :). The problem is that the columns are actually being created with other CTE's above, so there is a code to make that table as well. I just added the code in the question from the second CTE

Comment: it might be a bit stupid but can you confirm how this macro works? from my understanding: The first for loop is running the macro  8 times since the for loop runs for a number of columns i.e 8. Then after running 8 times, the loop is finished and now it runs the second loop?  that actually takes the values generated i.e 1 or 0  and sums them up ? is that correct ? If yes, then how is the macro storing the values 1 and 0 from the first loop in the first place

Comment: are you sure that `new_col1 + new_col3 + new_col5 + new_col7`  in you compile version shows that : each of the column actually is the result of the first macro i.e either contains 1 or 0 as value and sums them up. For example `new_col1` would be actually be the result of the following:  `if(ifnull(xx_col1 != xx_col2,true) is true,1,0)` and if this returns true then the value of `new_col1` would be 1. Similary, all of those values be generated and summed up

Comment: idk if bigquery supports lateral column aliases (which is what it's called when you use an alias in the same subquery that defines it), but this would work on Snowflake. If not, then move the `as ...` out of the macro and just call the macro again from the second loop

Comment: i don't think you can refer the column generated by the code in the same query in bigquery, that is though possible in snowflake as you mentioned. Can you adjust the code accordingly ? as I would actually need to have those 8 columns from the macro as well as the final sum column

Comment: hey i tried to use your set columns logic for another case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519976/dbt-jinja-macro-to-pass-set-of-columns-to-a-list-and-perform-calculations-and-re However, it is not working as expected. Can you help there ?