# dbt Jinja macro to pass set of columns to a list and perform calculations and renaming

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I have a code below where:

1. I am fetching all the relevant columns from two tables and renaming them to a similar keyword,
2. bringing all the data into 1 row.
3. running a macro to identify mismatch

I would like to see the final names of each column as `s1_xxx` or `s2_xxx`. s1_ indicates the column is from **table 1** and s2_xxx indicates it is from **table2**

The problem is that I have to pass the columns as a tuple/list as `where format('%t', (s1_id,s1_qty,s1_price)) != format('%t', (s2_id,s2_qty,s2_price))`. But there could be multiple columns, in my example I am just showing 3. So the code could go like:

`(s1_id,s1_qty,s1_price, s1_aa, s1_ab, s1_ac.......n)`. In that case, it doesn't look that readable

```
with source1 as (
select 
b.id as s1_id,
b.qty as s1_qty,
a.price as s1_price
from <table> as a
,unnest <details> as b
 where b.status != 'canceled'
),

source2 as (
select 
un_id  as s2_id, 
acqty_ as s2_qty, 
price_per_unit as s2_price  
from <table2>
where city != 'delhi'
) ,

compare as (
select *
from source1 s1
full outer join source2 s2
on id = id_
where format('%t', (s1_id,s1_qty,s1_price)) != format('%t', (s2_id,s2_qty,s2_price))
)

Select 

*,   {{ create_calc(s1_price,s2_price) }} ,   {{ create_calc(s1_qty,s2_qty) }}

from compare
## this would then generate two columns:

**is_price_mismatch and is_qty_mismatch** based on the macro (see below)
```

{{ create_calc(col1,col2) }} indicates the following:

```
{% macro create_calc(col1, col2) -%}
if(ifnull({{ col1 }} != {{ col2 }},true) is true,1,0) as {{ col1 | replace(‘s1_,'is_') }}_mismatch
{% endmacro %}
```

I wanted to check if it is possible to use jinja to kind of define the columns in a list/tuple and then pass it in the `where` clause (see below):

`where format('%t', (s1_id,s1_qty,s1_price))` would convert to something like:

`where format('%t', list)` but even if I do this I will have to create two lists ? as the names of the columns have different prefixes s1_xx, s2_xx :

1. `col_list = (s1_id, s1_qty, s1_price,.......n)`
2. `col_list2 = (s2_id, s2_qty, s2_price,.......n)`

And then passing it to `where` clause:

`where format('%t', (col_list)) != format('%t', (col_list2))`

**or** is there a way I can pass one list and rename the columns along with it via some code?

`col_list = (id, qty, price)` ## note the the

final output would then be:

- s1_id,
- s1_qty,
- s1_price,
- s2_id,
- s2_qty,
- s2_price
- is_price_mismatch
- is_qty_mismatch

I was hoping someone can help me how I can code this logic or maybe any other solution that would work with my existing code above / minor adjustments

**Update:**

I tried the following logic:

`{% set cols = ("price" , "qty") %}`

and passed it to my `format()`:

`format('%t',{{ cols }}) as serial`

but the results are not correct somehow the `'` is being attached to the beginning and ending of the column names: (can be seen in the compiled version:

`format('%t',('price', 'quantity')) as serial`

what i need is:

`format('%t',(price, quantity)) as serial`

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved using two ways:

```
{% set cols = ('id' , 'qty') %}


## and then using 

format('%t',{{ cols_ | replace('\'','') }})
```

or

```
{% set cols = 'id,quantity' %}


## and then using : 

format('%t',({{ cols_ }})) as d365_cols
```